# Is it possible to allow users to purchase simple products and nominal products (subscriptions) together with Credit Card in Magento?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to allow users to purchase simple products and nominal products (subscriptions) together with Credit Card in Magento?

Presently PayPal does not allow to purchase products and nominal products (subscriptions) together for sure.
But is there any possibility that we can allow this payment using Credit Card?

If yes, then will there be any issue with the recurring payments received from customers?

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept subscriptions (which is a pci compliance issue but specific to your gateway and processor)

Aheadworks has a subscriptions and recurring payments module that would allow you to accept subscriptions and regular items to be purchased at checkout. Hope this helps